# Scala Function1 Generic parameter and return type

Tags: scala, function, types

Lets say I want to store a `Map[String, Function1]` where the parameter and return type of the Function1 can vary. How would I go about storing a `Function1[String, String]` and `Function1[Int, Int]` in the same Map.

I've tried `Function1[AnyRef, AnyRef]` but `Function1[String, String]` isn't a `Function1[AnyRef, AnyRef]` so it fails to compile.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a type safe way

Comment: Can you store an ADT, i.e. `sealed trait MyFn | case class Fn1(f: Int => Int) extends MyFn | case class Fn2(f: String => String)`? Then, pattern match on the `Map#get` result, i.e. `Option[MyFn]`.

Comment: The type that would compile is `Nothing => Any`, it would accept any function. See `val f: Nothing => Any = (a: String) => a.toInt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only two possible value types, you can wrap values in [Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Either.html):

```
val m = Map[String, Either[Int => Int, String => String]]()
```

If you want to store more than two different types, create your own wrapper, or use something like [Coproduct from shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#coproducts-and-discriminated-unions).

Answer (score 2):

Does this look like what you're after?

```
scala> val m = Map[String, Function1[_,_]]()
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Function1[_, _]] = Map()

scala> val f1 = (i:Int) => i*3
f1: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val f2 = (b: Boolean) => if (b) "YES" else "NO"
f2: Boolean => String = <function1>

scala> m + ("xcx" -> f2) + ("rtr" -> f1)
res59: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Function1[_, _]] = Map(xcx -> <function1>, rtr -> <function1>)
```

Comment: I don't thin you can actually use the functions after retrieving them from the map

Comment: The retrieved function is usable but you have to cast it, `m("rtr").asInstanceOf[Function1[Int,Int]](4)`, which is a pretty good indication that you need to rethink this approach.

Comment: The goal of this is to hold a bunch of transforming functions for fields of a class. So given a list of POJOs (or Scala equivalent classes), get the fields of the class of the object (e.g. val someString, val someInt, etc.) and apply a given function that can return any other type (e.g. converting someString to aLong) by the name of said field using reflection, for every item in the list of POJOs.